# Constraints on digital mp3/wav sound reproduction?

Tags: acoustics, vibrations

A recent tv broadcast on http://www.cuny.tv/ discussed a new and successful business startup in new york city selling vinyl LP's. Sorry, I can't find that episode, but I think it's this company http://nypost.com/2017/06/01/millennial-vinyl-startup-cues-up-success/ (or one pretty much like it).

Apparently, analog/vinyl has a "warmer" sound that digital/mp3/wav can't achieve. And maybe it's more an engineering question, but why not??? That is, given a **high enough sampling rate** and a **lossless format**, then regardless of the "harshness" of individual samples, I'd think the overall effect could accurately reproduce any "musical quality". Ultimately, a waveform's a waveform, and if you reproduce it, then you've reproduced all its "qualities". Or so I'd think.

Maybe you'd need a zillion samples-per-second, and maybe you'd need lossless wav format rather than lossy mp3, but I'd think it should be possible to re-master a vinyl original (even when played through some analog/tube-based amplifier) to a digital format, and accurately reproduce every conceivable musical nuance. But the success of these vinyl companies seems to suggest otherwise. So what am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is firstly that records are physically enjoyable to play -- the whole ritual is fun -- and secondly that almost everything related to hifi is surrounded by weird pseudoscientific cults.  (I am writing this comment as someone who owns many records and has several valve (tube) amplifiers including one I made: I run one of these cults)

Comment: The MP3 issue is totally different from WAV. MP3 is a lossy compression where "lossy" directly translates to sound distortions. These distortions are not always apparent. For example, it is virtually impossible to tell the difference on computer speakers. However on a high quality stereo system the difference becomes self evident and quite pronounced.

Comment: Would be an interesting experiment to put a vinyl disc on a turntable but play the source from a CD or high bit rate MP3 and see if the listener notices

Comment: Beware trying to argue with any audiophile who claims to have "[Golden Ears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ear)."

Comment: @Martin Beckett: This has been done by many (me included). In general, MP3 is not a High End standard for music reproduction. There is a competition between WAV and vinyl, but MP3 is inferior to both and does not compete for a high quality sound. Here "high quality" implies a high resolution stereo system. If you compare on computer speakers or in most headphones, there is hardly any difference among all three, because the quality is limited by the equipment, not by the format. Go to the AXPONA show in Chicago  to hear the vinyl setup by Pass Labs on 12th floor. You won't believe your ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In digital music, the data consists of sample values and time intervals between samples. While these time intervals should all be the same in a given song, in reality their value fluctuates causing timing distortions of the resulting sound wave. These distortions are called jitter or phase noise and sound harsh. It so happens that the human ear is amazingly hypersensitive to this type of distortions and an enthusiast listener can easily tell the difference between two different quality quartz crystals stabilizing the timing of the signal.

This in itself is not a problem yet. The actual problem comes from the way the digital music distribution standard was set up. Initially the idea was to convert the digital signal from a CD to the analog format in the CD player. For this purpose a digital protocol was developed called I2s that properly supported both, signal values and timing. However, this protocol was designed as a short range type to be used only inside the CD player.

Later people started making higher quality digital to analog converters (DACs) in separate enclosures with digital inputs thus requiring a digital output from a CD player. Because I2s was a short range protocol, a different protocol was used for digital outputs called SPDIF (Sony/Philips Digital Interchange Protocol). It is the shortcomings of this protocol that have caused a massive dissatisfaction by the digital standard and a resurrection of vinyl.

The problem of SPDIF is that it passes only the value samples, but does not pass the time interval data between samples. Superficially it seems trivial: all intervals are the same, why do we need to pass each one? However, things weren't so simple. With no timing information, we must use a different clock (quartz crystal) in the DAC. However, no two clocks are the same. The frequency difference would eventually break the playback by putting it out of sync with the transmission. For this reason, initially, instead of a high quality quartz resonator, the signal timing in DACs was derived from SPDIF by a PLL (Phase Locked Loop) circuit. The timing precision of this circuit is limited by the time delay required for analyzing the signal. We don't want the music delay to be too long and this limits the precision and increases the jitter to very much audible levels.

A massive dissatisfaction with SPDIF along with the emergence of computer music have caused a development of a new protocol called USB Audio, specifically its third iteration called Async USB Audio. This protocol for the first time uses the quartz clock in the DAC and sends timing commands to the player. In theory this should eliminate the transmission jitter and finally after 35 years of the digital disaster resolve the timing issue. In reality this has not happened. The new protocol still has numerous shortcomings. For example, it is not error correcting. If you use USB to copy a file to a disk, transmission errors happen all the time, but they are corrected by a retransmission and the file always copies correctly. Not so in USB Audio, no retransmissions there. All transmission errors are passed to the DAC and reproduced as audible distortions. This is the main reason for why a USB cable affects the sound quality. There are other numerous issues with USB, including poor quality power supplies, galvanic isolation from the player, etc.

It takes a lot of effort, but it is possible to make Async USB Audio sound better then vinyl. I have accomplished this in my digital setup that now is better than my High End vinyl turntable. However I can attest that this is not possible without specialized equipment and expertise.

There are other efforts underway to resolve the digital fiasco:

1. Using higher bitrates. Most people don't know that the main purpose of higher bitrates is to reduce jitter. Higher bitrates contain virtually no additional musical information, all they do is reduce the transmission jitter.
2. DSD or Direct Stream Digital (SACD) also reduces the transmission jitter and is being resurrected now along with vinyl.
3. Some units used I2s inputs and outputs, but this is uncommon.
4. New network based audio protocols show a promise, but only slowly gain recognition.
5. Integrated players do not have this timing problem (e.g. portable players or DACs that accept SD memory cards).
6. Low jitter variable frequency quartz resonators have been recently developed.
7. Various after market "reclockers" are sold to improve the timing of the digital signal.

To summarize, the main digital problem is the signal timing between the player and DAC due to poorly designed digital interface protocols. Vinyl records do not have this problem. Note that most vinyl records are digitally mastered, but still sound warm and "analog", because the problem is not in the digital format. The problem is in the use of inferior transmission protocols in consumer equipment.

The digital technology breaks the music into bits and then puts the bits back together. If you break a crystal vase into pieces and then glue them back together, it would never look the same no matter how hard you try.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed discussion. Re "digitally mastered vinyl", **that's** what particularly struck me in the tv broadcast I mentioned in original post, prompting me to ask the question. The broadcast included a tour of this company's own sound studio, where they cut acetate masters of live artist performances, **entirely analog**, no digital whatsoever, and then press vinyl from that. Seemed to me like a disservice to their artists, unnecessarily restricting their potential audience by maybe 99.9%. And I couldn't (and now still can't) imagine why they'd do it that way.

Comment: They usually do it both ways, all analog ending up on vinyl plus also digitized ending up on a CD. So all market is covered. In other words, the fact that they make all analog vinyl does not necessarily mean that they don't make CDs in addition. For example, I own a recent all analog vinyl release of the Beatles in mono, but I also have them in mono on CDs. The reason for all analog is an accumulated distrust of a consumer segment in anything digital. Studio digital equipment is better due to the use of a master clock, but nothing is perfect. A lot also depends on the recording engineer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a waveform is a waveform and faking it is possible. You could copy vinyl into another format to the point of being indistinguishable to a human.

Maybe each play degrades the vinyl just a little bit so it's subtly different each time, making it feel more human. Maybe each vinyl disc has slightly different imperfections. Maybe faking is frowned upon, just like having a car play sporty engine noises with a speaker.

Comment: The spelling for optical and vinyl media is "disc" while "disk" refers to computer magnetic hard drives.

Comment: The rules I found with a quick were for optical vs magnetic (no mention of vinyl), and they were loose guidelines rather than hard spelling rules, but I'll edit it, anyway.

Comment: Right, this is because vinyl is usually referred to as "records".